# Updating field on clicking the link on a email alert

Tags: workflowrule

Is there any way to update a field when the receiver of email alert clicks on the 
link to record provided on the email alert?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it by just addding a param to URL in your link then when user clicks on the link check for param and update the record using your controller. In VF page add action that would do it, prior to that check if the record is not updated to prevent multiple updates. You can do the same in Lightining using 
lightning:isUrlAddressable interface and then grab it in your component on init

```
var pageReference = component.get("v.pageReference");
var updateRecord = component.get("v.pageReference").state.updateRecord;
```

Either way it is not complicated.